# Bigquery Command line 'bq load' from gcs is failing. Traceback shows 'ReadFileContents' attribute missing in google-cloud-sdk's bootstrapping module

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sdk

Below is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bq.py", line 86, in <module>
    exceptions.HandleError(e, 'bq')
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/exceptions.py", line 526, in HandleError

  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/exceptions.py", line 137, in reraise
    """Adds tb or the most recent traceback to exc_value and reraises."""
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bq.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bq.py", line 29, in main
    version = bootstrapping.ReadFileContents('platform/bq', 'VERSION')
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 288, in ReadFileContents
    return files.ReadFileContents(os.path.join(SDK_ROOT, *path_parts)).strip()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ReadFileContents'
```

Comment: read the version of the util and report a bug